# Environment.Exit() causes my application to crash after using Process.Start

Tags: c#, winforms, crash, backgroundworker, environment

I have a small form that creates two background worker threads which listen for messages from two separate server processes.  When the user attempts to close the form, I handle the OnFormClosing event (or they can click an 'Exit menu item) which calls CancelAsync() on both threads.  The form then waits until the IsBusy property for both threads is "FALSE" before calling Environment.Exit(0).

Here is the catch:  From this Form, the user is able to launch a separate application.  This is done using Process.Start when a specific button is clicked.  If the user has created a new process via the Form, and then closes the Form, instead of exiting gracefully it crashes and I get one of those windows error messages.  Application.Exit doesn't work because it won't close the form for some reason unbeknown to me.  I'm certain that both threads are finished executing because I handle the RunWorkerCompleted event for both threads.  Here is a shell of the core code:

```
private void startProcess_buttonClick(sender, e)
{
      Process.Start(<process args>);
}


protected override OnFormClosing()
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    if (!thread1.IsBusy && !thread2.IsBusy)
       Environment.Exit(0);

    stopThreads();
}
private void stopThreads()
{
   if (thread1.IsBusy)
       thread1.CancelAsync();

   if (thread2.IsBusy)
       thread2.CancelAsync();
}

private void thread1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender, e)
{
       if (!thread2.IsBusy)
          Environment.Exit(0);
}


private void thread2_RunWorkerCompleted(sender, e)
{
       if (!thread1.IsBusy)
          Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Any ideas as to what would be causing the crash on Environment.Exit?

Comment: Have you looked at the event log? It will log the exact error.

Comment: Here is what it reads:  "EventType clr20r3; P1 ccs_wsdt.exe, P2 1.0.0.0. P3 4cb0eeb3. P4 system.windows.forms. P5 2.0.0.0. P6 471ebf68. P7 16c6. P8 159. P9 system.componentmodel.win32. P10 NIL"

No idea how to interpret that.  The code/application is run on an offline network, so I have to manually type everything in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Application.Exit()
```

since you're running Windows Forms. I haven't made a test case by myself, but I'm pretty sure that Winforms APIs are *unhappy* about the immediate termination of a process via Environment, which uses kernel APIs.

I also found this: http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

Comment: I've tried application.Exit...it doesn't exit my application.

Comment: Actually, after fixing some other stuff, I tried Application.Exit again and it crashes as well.

Comment: Can you catch any exception somewhere? Try hooking to Application.ThreadException and do MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString), it could help you more!

Comment: ^^ I tried that out per this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

My application isn't catching any exceptions, but it doesn't appear to be crashing any more either...wish I understood why.  Going to test it some more and see if it's actually working now or if it just hasn't crashed by chance yet.

Comment: I had same issue and tried is solution but now I am getting the exit message twice ! and tired this.close(); but it dose nothing

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
protected override OnFormClosing()
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    if (!thread1.IsBusy && !thread2.IsBusy)
       this.Close();

    stopThreads();
}
private void thread1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender, e)
{
       if (!thread2.IsBusy)
          this.Close();
}
private void thread2_RunWorkerCompleted(sender, e)
{
       if (!thread1.IsBusy)
          this.Close();
}
```